# How can I start VirtualBox with an image of Kali Linux?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, disk-image, file-type

On my Ubuntu system VirtualBox 5.0 is unable to locate the virtual optical image of Kali Linux 2.0. This is the message:

```
Failed to open the disk image file /home/saiyad/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vbox-amd64.7z.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/saiyad/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vbox-amd64.7z' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

How can I get VirtualBox to use this image?

Comment: Maybe the disk image file is 7z compressed? Have you tried uncompressing it into being an uncompressed iso image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the compressed File.

1. Right Click on `Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vbox-amd64.7z`
2. Click on extract here. "extracting can take a long time."

   [image]
3. Open up `VirtualBox` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

   [image]
4. click on [image] to navigate to your
   extracted file and select it then click Open.

   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Next ></kbd>
6. Click <kbd>Import</kbd>

   [image]

   This May Take a while.
   [image]

now you are all Good to go to start Kali-Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should extract the image file. It's still a 7z file.

```
7z x Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vbox-amd64.7z
```

Then VirtualBox should recognize the extracted file (should be an ova file, based on Neil's answer).

If 7z is not installed, run `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` first before running the above file.